# Why is my Hippomock expectation failing when using multiple inheritance

Tags: c++, inheritance, mocking, hippomocks

I am using Hippomocks and have a class that implements an generic interface. When I place expectations on this class I do not get the expected behaviour.

This is my minimum "working" example

```
template <class T>
struct Foo {
  virtual ~Foo() = default;
  virtual void bar(const T& t) = 0;
};

struct Baz : public Foo<int>, public Foo<double> {
  void bar(const int& t) override = 0;
  void bar(const double& t) override = 0;
};

TEST_CASE("Foo")
{
  MockRepository mocks;

  auto baz = mocks.Mock<Baz>();

  mocks.ExpectCall(baz, Foo<int>::bar);
  baz->bar(12);

  mocks.ExpectCall(baz, Foo<double>::bar);
  baz->bar(234.3);
}
```

I am expecting this test to pass without any problems. However the test fails with the following message (slightly edited to remove project names):

```
test_foo.cpp|28| FAILED:
|| due to unexpected exception with message:
||   Function called without expectation!
||   Expectations set:
||   test_foo.cpp(31)
||   : Expectation for Foo<int>::bar(...) on the mock at 0x0x5569df8f3400 was
||   satisfied.
||   test_foo.cpp(34)
||   : Expectation for Foo<double>::bar(...) on the mock at 0x0x5569df8f3400 was
||   not satisfied.
```

```
I am expecting the bar() belonging to Foo<double> to be invoked.
```

Answer (score 1):

I was curious how `Mock` could be possibly implemented without manually defining all the methods (like other mocking libraries do), but it turns out that it does not work. `Mock` implementation employs Undefined Behavior because it just [`reinterpret_cast` unrelated class to `Baz`](https://github.com/dascandy/hippomocks/blob/10960d027b398444ec3ec6ce2487de3db0283ff8/HippoMocks/hippomocks.h#L6326):

```
template <typename base>
base *MockRepository::Mock() {
    mock<base> *m = new mock<base>(this);
        mocks.push_back(m);
    return reinterpret_cast<base *>(m);
}
```

It does various other cheesy things, such as messing with vtable. None of that stuff can work reliably.

Answer (score 0):

Hippomocks takes care of the case in which there are overloaded class functions.

The expectations I should have used are the following

```
  mocks.ExpectCallOverload(baz, static_cast<void (Baz::*)(const int&)>(&Baz::bar));
  baz->bar(12);

  mocks.ExpectCallOverload(baz, static_cast<void (Baz::*)(const double&)>(&Baz::bar));
  baz->bar(234.3);
```

The syntax is horrible, but this now behaves as expected.

I should have RTFM...